# Random tree with specific branching factor in Mathematica

Tags: graph, tree, wolfram-mathematica

Do you know if it's possible to somehow generate a random tree graph with a specific branching factor? I don't want it to be a k-ary tree.

It would be also great if I could define both the branching factor and the maximum depth. I want to randomly generate a bunch of trees that would differ in branching factor and depth.

TreePlot with random integer input returns something that's almost what I want:

```
TreePlot[RandomInteger[#] -> # + 1 & /@ Range[0, 100]]
```

[image: TreePlot result]

but I can't figure out a way to get a tree with a specific branching factor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I guess I'm a bit late, but I like the question. Instead of creating a tree in the form

```
{0 -> 1, 0 -> 5, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4}
```

I will use the following form of nested calls, where every argument is a child, which represents another node

```
0[1[2, 3, 4], 5]
```

Both forms are equivalent and can be transformed into each other.

```
Row[{
  TreeForm[0[1[2, 3, 4], 5]],
  TreePlot[{0 -> 1, 0 -> 5, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4}]
  }]
```

[image: Tree]

Here is how the algorithm works: As arguments we need a function `f` which gives a random number of children and is called when we create a node. Additionally, we have a depth `d` which defines the maximum depth a (sub-)tree can have.

1. **[Choose branching]** Define a branching function `f` which can be called like `f[]` and returns a random number of children. If you want a tree with either 2 or 4 children, you could use e.g. `f[] := RandomChoice[{2, 4}]`. This function will be called for each created node in the tree.
2. **[Choose tree-depth]** Choose a maximum depth `d` of the tree. At this point, I'm not sure what you want the randomness to be incorporated into the generation of the tree. What I do here is that when a new node is created, the depth of the tree below it is randomly chosen between the depth of its parent minus one and zero.
3. **[Create ID Counter]** Create a unique counter variable `count` and set it to zero. This will give us increasing node ID's. When creating a new node, it is increased by 1.
4. **[Create a node]** Increase `count` and use it as node-ID. If the current depth `d` is zero, give back a leaf with ID count, otherwise call `f` to decide how many children the node should get. For every new child chose randomly the depth of its sub-tree which can be `0,...,d-1` and call 4. for each new child. When all recursive calls have returned, the tree is built.

Fortunately, in *Mathematica*-code this procedure is not so verbose and consists only of a few lines. I hope you can find in the code what I have described above

```
With[{counter = Unique[]},
 generateTree[f_, d_] := (counter = 0; builder[f, d]);
 builder[f_, d_] := Block[
   {nodeID = counter++, childs = builder[f, #] & /@ RandomInteger[d - 1, f[]]},
   nodeID @@ childs
 ];
 builder[f_, 0] := (counter++);
]
```

Now you can create a random tree like follows

```
branching[] := RandomChoice[{2, 4}];
t = generateTree[branching, 6];
TreeForm[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or if you like you can use the next function to convert the tree into what is accepted by `TreePlot`

```
transformTree[tree_] := Module[{transform},
  transform[(n_Integer)[childs__]] := (Sow[
     n -> # & /@ ({childs} /. h_Integer[__] :> h)]; 
    transform /@ {childs});
  Flatten@Last@Reap[transform[tree]
]
```

and use it to create many random trees

```
trees = Table[generateTree[branching, depth], {depth, 3, 7}, {5}];
GraphicsGrid[Map[TreePlot[transformTree[#]] &, trees, {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]